# How to measure the depth of a file system path?

Tags: macos, bash, command-line, terminal

I'm looking for a way to do this on the command line, since this is not too hard a task in `Java` or `Python`.

Something like:

```
$ measure_depth /a/b/c/d/e/f
6
$ measure_depth /a
1
```

This question is functionally equivalent to "is there an easy way to count the number of slashes in a filename?"

Comment: What depth do you want for `measure_depth /`?  For `measure_depth /a/` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a measure_depth function:

```
measure_depth() { echo "${*#/}" | awk -F/ '{print NF}'; }
```

Then, use it as follows:

```
$ measure_depth /a/b/c/d/e/f
6
$ measure_depth /a
1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
tr -s "/" "\n" | wc -l
```

which gives you an extra one, so a "hacky" way around it would be

```
sed "s/^\///" | tr -s "/" "\n" | wc -l

echo "/a/b/c/d/e/f" | sed "s/^\///" | tr -s "/" "\n" | wc -l
6
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `realpath` before counting the slashes to avoid overestimations as e.g. `/home/user/../user/../user/../user/dir/` would be translated to `/home/user/dir`.

```
realpath <dir> | grep -o '/' | wc -l
```

Comment: The OP is using OS X not Linux, as noted by the Tags, and `realpath` does not by default exist in OS X nor it it installed by default in some modern Linux Distros, e.g., Linux Mint 17.1 and requires installing it manually after the fact by one way or another. It is a part of GNU coreutils and can be installed using Homebrew or manually if Command Line Tools for OS X is installed. That said, John1024's answer is IMO the best one presented so far.