# Shell scripting-subdirectories calculation

Tags: shell

Write a shell script takes the name a path (eg: /afs/andrew/course/15/123/handin), and counts all the sub directories (recursively).

Ex. /afs/andrew/course/15/123/handin should give me 6. 
I tried with the Find command,but the path which i am giving is being accepted.

Comment: You can count sub-directories using :  
find <path> -type d | wc -l

Comment: your question becomes easier to answer, if you post the full command you tried, how the directory structure is and what you got as an output

Comment: I guess that some class is having an exam.  This question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31528199/how-to-measure-the-depth-of-a-file-system-path/

Comment: ...and I *seriously* dislike answering "homework" questions, especially when they look like this (copypasta from the assignment paper by a 1-rep user).

Answer (score 0):

simple AWK can do that

```
root@freebsd:~ # echo /afs/andrew/course/15/123/handin | awk -F / '{ print NF-1}'
6
root@freebsd:~ #
```